# Draw thousands of small images on threejs point cloud

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

I'm new to this. I need to draw thousands of small images in threejs point cloud using array of textures.But it seems limited if I use **sampler2d** array, can't exceed array size more than 30 .Is there a better workaround to do this?

This is my workaround and it can only draw 30 images

Shaders:

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">
    attribute float texIndex;
    uniform float size;
    varying vec3 vColor;
    varying float vTexIndex;

    void main() {
        vColor = color;
        vTexIndex = texIndex;
        vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
        gl_PointSize = size * ( size / (length(mvPosition.xyz) + 1.0) );
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    }
</script>

<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">
    uniform sampler2D tex[30];
    varying vec3 vColor;
    varying float vTexIndex;
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = vec4( vColor.x, vColor.x, vColor.x, 1.0 );
        if(vTexIndex < 1.5} ){ 
            gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D(tex[0], gl_PointCoord); 
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
    }   
</script>
```

JS:

````
    var indexArray = [0.0,1.0,2.0, .............];
    var textures = [
         THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("img/0.png"),
         THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("img/1.png"),
         THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("img/2.png"),
         .
         .
         .
         .
    ];
    
    
    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
        fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
        vertexShader: vertexShader,
        depthWrite: true,
        depthTest: true,
        attributes: {
            texIndex : { value: indexArray},                    
        },
        uniforms: {
            size: { type: "f", value: 20 },
            tex: { type: "tv", value: textures }
            
        }
    });```
````